# ADB not responding

Tags: ventura, android

Multiple times per day. ADB suddenly stops responding. Every `adb` shell command never finishes or produces any output. IntelliJ and Android Studio do not recognise my phone(s) anymore.

The solution is simple. Use

```
killall adb
```

But I have to do this about 20 times a day and it starts to get annoying. Any idea how to fix this?

New M2 Macbook Pro, 3 weeks old. Ventura 13.6

ADB was installed through the Jetbrains SDK Manager:

[image: Screenshot fo Jetbrains SDK Manager]

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253649/44325